# Rendering glyph using HTML file

Tags: html, css, svg, glyphicons

I need some insights on how to do this:
I have a scraped `.html` file which has the full structure which it has some references in there to a *custom* font-family.

I was able to track that font-family and found that it was a giant `.svg` file. I took all the contents from the .svg file and placed the svg code inside the HTML file.

So here is what I currently have:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="https://test.com/"><i class="search">INSERT ICON</i></a>

    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
<font id="testicons" horiz-adv-x="1024">
<font-face units-per-em="1024" ascent="960" descent="-64" />
<missing-glyph horiz-adv-x="1024" />
<glyph unicode="&#x20;" horiz-adv-x="512" d="" />
<glyph unicode="&#xe900;" glyph-name="badge_icon" d="M511.986 58.88c76.042 0 148.972 30.836 202.742 85.726 53.77 54.886 83.978 129.331 83.978 206.957 0 77.623-30.208 152.067-83.978 206.957s-126.7 85.725-202.742 85.725c-76.042 0-148.972-30.835-202.741-85.725s-83.978-129.335-83.978-206.957c0-77.626 30.208-152.071 83.978-206.957 53.77-54.89 126.699-85.726 202.741-85.726zM461.81 415.075l35.652 57.767c6.67 10.803 22.378 10.803 29.047 0l35.652-57.767 63.208-11.677c12.356-2.28 18.094-16.678 10.694-26.832l-42.895-58.87 7.697-64.672c1.485-12.472-10.557-22.224-22.449-18.173l-66.43 22.634-70.499-21.972c-12.22-3.809-24.129 6.694-21.879 19.296l11.237 62.887-44.107 58.658c-7.636 10.151-1.898 24.788 10.602 27.051l64.471 11.67zM351.099 857.6h141.558v-172.682c-100.27-6.811-155.977-47.214-186.121-76.382v204.191c0 24.783 19.952 44.873 44.563 44.873zM678.782 857.6h-141.558v-172.682c100.27-6.811 155.976-47.214 186.122-76.382v204.191c0 24.783-19.954 44.873-44.564 44.873z" />
</font></defs></svg>
```

So I would love to be able to use the glyph `badge_icon` and render it inside my `<i>` tag, is this possible in HTML?

Comment: [Only Safari supports svg fonts...](https://caniuse.com/svg-fonts), and it's been deprecated in SVG2, so no hope to see it in others any time. Your best bet would be to use a tool that helps generate custom fonts, for instance I personally use [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/app/) occasionally. Also note that if you are not the author of this glyph, you might not have the rights to use it, check with the original authors if they are ok with you doing what you plan to do.

Comment: If you want SVG icons from any iconset in a modern browser, see the ``<svg-icon>`` Web Component at https://IconMeister.github.io